# How to unit test pubsub Receive callback

Tags: unit-testing, go, callback, google-cloud-pubsub

I have the following production code:

```
func pullMessages(ctx context.Context, sub *pubsub.Subscription) {
    err := sub.Receive(ctx, func(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {
        log.Printf("Got message: %q\n", string(msg.Data))
        processMessage(msg)
        msg.Ack()
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Receive: %v", err)
    }
}
```

How can I verify `processMessage` is actually being called in a unit test ?

Comment: You can define a `type messageProcessor interface { processMessage(msg)}`, pass an instance of `messageProcessor` to `pullMessages`, and then mock it to intercept calls to `processMessage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple: make your callback a named function instead of an anonymous one:

```golang
func pullMessages(ctx context.Context, sub *pubsub.Subscription) {
    if err := sub.Receive(ctx, rcvCallback); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Receiving message: %s",err)
    }
}

func rcvCallback (ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {
        log.Printf("Got message: %q\n", string(msg.Data))
        processMessage(msg)
        msg.Ack()
}
```

Now, in your unit tests, you can create an instance of a `Context` and a `Message` and pass it to your function. However, in this case, that barely makes sense. You do little more than logging and acknowledging the message, functions which should be unit tested by the upstream project. Hence it would make more sense to construct an instance of message and unit test `processMessage`.

Comment: Thanks Markus but I still did not figure out how to mock the message so `msg.Ack()` does not get actually called, because if it does the test crashes.

Comment: Again: do NOT test `rvcCallBack` in this case. Test `processMessage` only. As long as `msg.Ack()` isn't called in there (and why should it?), you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks again, let's leave `rcvCallback` untested. If I just move `msg.Ack()` downstream (which I would not like as the file where it resides now is dedicated to pubsub stuff) I will still have the need to assert that `msg.Ack()` is actually being called after `processMessage()` succeeds. Then my problem remains, how to mock `msg` so I do not end up calling the real `Ack()` function.

Comment: You do not call the Ack function in your unit tests - you call it in integation tests. And you do not mock msg, but pass a real instance of `pubsub.Message`

Comment: Unfortunately, Google has not really designed the pubsub interface in a way that is very easy to unit-test. As noted, calling msg.Ack() will cause a nil pointer exception if the message object is created by your test code.